# Multiple RadioGroup onCheckedChanged

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

This is my first time doing radio groups. Im trying to save the values from 3 groups to Shared Prefs. It works fine with one group, but once I try to add 2 more, all the pref values are just the last group in the form. Im not sure what to do to use multiple RadioGroups. Any help would be appreciated.

onCreate

```
RadioGroup radioGroupGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio);
radioGroupGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

RadioGroup radioGroupActivity = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_level);
radioGroupActivity.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

RadioGroup radioGroupStatus = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.current_status);
radioGroupStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

And my onCheckedChanged

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        int genderId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton genderBut = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(genderId);
        gender_radio = genderBut.getText().toString();

        int activityLvl = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton activityLvlBut = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(activityLvl);
        activity_level = activityLvlBut.getText().toString();

        int currentStat = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton CurrentBut = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(currentStat);
        current_status = CurrentBut.getText().toString();
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `findViewById()` for each `RadioButton` on the `radioGroup` parameter passed into `onCheckedChanged()`. That parameter will be the `RadioGroup` that's currently changing. You need to look for a given group's checked ID in that specific group; e.g., the first one would be `RadioButton genderBut = (RadioButton) radioGroupGender.findViewById(genderId);`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `gender_radio` `activity_level` `current_status` , they get overwriten on every `onCheckedChanged()` call, only the values of the last call of `onCheckedChanged()` will be saved